# Horizontal scroll - Mobile - swipe?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, swipe

Can anyone please recommend the best way to trigger a horizontal Jquery scroller using swipe gesture?

We have a working web version which we would like to implement onto our Android site, but dont know the best way to approach this.

We basically want to use a scrolling list similar to these examples (http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/) triggered via swipe gesture?

Any advice or alternate versions gratefully received.

Cheers
Paul

Comment: You have the swipeleft and swiperight events? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Cheers Phill - I'll take a look at them

Comment: Note that swipe doesn't work in Firefox Fennec (it hijacks the left-right swipe gesture to show navigation buttons) or Opera Mini (unlike Opera Mobile, it doesn't support any touch events except tap), so you should provide alternate tap-friendly navigation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest the excellent jQuery TouchSwipe Plugin by Matt Bryson: http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/. This plugin offers advanced control over direction and distance: http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/advanced_2.php

An all inclusive alternative would be http://www.photoswipe.com/

similar question: [Calculate swipe distance in jQuery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924671/calculate-swipe-distance-in-jquery-mobile/8106972#8106972)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is such carousel controlled by swipe gestures. But it's commercial - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/ or [this one](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/).