# Metro menu theme in HTML5 (JQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How to create a menu, just like windows 8 start screen, using JQuery Mobile and HTML5?

Note: I'm not asking about metro theme controls, I'm talking about creating a menu with tiles like Windows 8 Start screen.

**EDIT : I know how to use JQuery Mobile, but I don't know how to create horizontal swiping...**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337110/horizontal-scroll-mobile-swipe might help.  Have you googled this at all?  What have you tried?

Comment: My question is clear. I want to create horizontal scrolling instead of vertical scrolling in **`JQuery Mobile`** platform. and my goal is creating something like Windows 8 Start menu using **JQuery Mobile**.

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting -3!

Comment: @Mahdi It is generally frowned upon to ask with question without any code or indication that any research was done on the topic, [here is a good resource for how to write good questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554).

Comment: Flag as : "not a real question
It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." Again I think the Title was misleading and the question was hard to understand

Comment: @Mahdi Your question showed no research effort. You basically asked a "gimme teh codez" question, which is not welcome on SO. I'd advise you to read the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update #2:

Found a live link:

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html ( <-- I think this is what you are looking for )

Updating my answer:

You should look into this:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview

It used to be live here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

But jQM has taken it down, not sure why.

It offered multi-directional scrolling

Does this work:

- http://sgrebnov.github.com/jqmobile-metro-theme/

Screen shots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would rephrase your question and title as it's miss leading "Metro menu theme in HTML5 (JQuery Mobile)", sounds like you wanted a theme. My mistake

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254761/jquery-mobile-scrollview

Comment: Thanks your updating your answer!

Comment: @Mahdi I also found a live example that I linked to as well, hope this helps