# jQuery Mobile Left/Right Swipe to Next Page not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I used jQuery Mobile Left/Right Swipe to Next Page but it not smooth anymore.I have to touch more than  2 times to swipe next/ previous page. (I tested on galaxy samsung tab and another app is run smoothly on this device), 
My code like this page
http://designicu.com/jquery-mobile-swipe/

Is there any way to resolve this ?
Thanks,

Comment: I would recommend if the answer helped to resolve the issue then please accept it as correct one.

Answer (score 5):

As jquery mobile is not very smooth in case of page transitions.Its better if we try to turn off all the page transitions  in jquery mobile.

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
```

you can also use

```
 <style>
    /*** for jquerymobile page flicker that was happening ***/
    .ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Also please go through following links.You might get what you are looking for.
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522886/jquery-mobile-ajax-is-enabled-by-default-but-i-get-full-page-refresh-on-post/16523902#16523902)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924671/calculate-swipe-distance-in-jquery-mobile)