# Jquery Mobile - Ajax is enabled by default but I get full page refresh on POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I created a `jQuery mobile` application using `ASP.NET MVC` and in the jQuery mobile documentation it's mentioned that Ajax is enabled by default for page transitions on clicking a link or submitting the form.

- In my case, when I submit the form,
- I get a full page refresh and I don't see the spinning loader.
- I get a flash of blank page and then page gets loaded.
- My page is similar to a survey page where one question will be displayed with list of options to select and then click Next.
- When user clicks Next it submits form and fetches next question via controller. So I am not sure what I am missing.

Please advise

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out to turn off the page transitions.Jquery mobile is still not very smooth in page transitions.May be that is causing the problem.

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
        });
```

Please refer

[jQuery Mobile flickering screen during transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029427/jquery-mobile-flickering-screen-during-transitions)

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Not exactly sure why. I did not set any transitions earlier but setting that to none did the trick.