# Phonegap transition jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with on transition jquery mobile, that for few milliseconds/seconds a white screen appears, which is pretty visible during transitions. Also I tried setting defaultPageTransition to none but that also didn't work. The problem still persists.

When I clicked on the link it changes page, but before changing page, it hides current page and after that white screen appears and then transition is made to next page. So here the White screen part is a problem. I was unable to replicate this problem on web browser or Testing through AVD Manager on emulator or Device. But issue occurs when making phonegap build and testing through the build.

Answer (score 1):

You can run that page in Chrome browser and you can see in the **Console** section for any errors (Press F12 to open the Console)

There you may find some errors that should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out to turn off the page transitions.Jquery mobile is still not very smooth in page transitions.May be that is causing the problem.

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
    });
```

[go through this and also following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522886/jquery-mobile-ajax-is-enabled-by-default-but-i-get-full-page-refresh-on-post/16523902#16523902)

[jQuery Mobile flickering screen during transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029427/jquery-mobile-flickering-screen-during-transitions)