# How to disable JQuery mobile side swipe in a if else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How would I go about disabling a sideswipe event in and if else statement? I have a table I want to swipe through but I want to disable it from swiping right if its at the beginning. I can't seem to find anything on goog.

```
function swiperighthandler (event) {
    if (whatever) {
        // code to disable the swipe
    }
    else {
        //Other code I want to run
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As jquery mobile is not very smooth in case of page transitions.Its better if we try to turn off all the page transitions  in jquery mobile.

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
```

you can also use

```
 <style>
    /*** for jquerymobile page flicker ***/
    .ui-page {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Also please go through following links.You might get what you are looking for.
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522886/jquery-mobile-ajax-is-enabled-by-default-but-i-get-full-page-refresh-on-post/16523902#16523902)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924671/calculate-swipe-distance-in-jquery-mobile)